# Transpose Columns of a DataFrame Based on Repeating - pandas

Tags: python

Hi I am having below screenshot as dataset

I looking something similar below please need help

[image]

```
       Aug-01 Sep-02 Oct-04 Nov-04 Jan-05 Feb-05 Mar-05 
MMC LTI 0      0      0      0      0      0      0      
MMC NIL 1      3      6      9      2      8      1      
MMC SIL 4      4      4      4      4      4      4      
MMC MIL 6      5      6      7      6      9      6      
SMN LTI 8      8      8      2      8      8      8      
SMN NIL 4      2      4      5      2      7      4      
SMN SIL 2      6      2      3      2      2      0      
SMN MIL 0      0      0      0      0      0      0      
EWC LTI 5      5      5      5      5      5      5      
EWC NIL 2      2      2      2      2      2      2      
EWC SIL 0      0      0      0      0      0      0      
EWC MIL 6      25     54     3      6      3      1
```

Comment: Please include the actual data - both input and desired output - as text in your post. Also, please try to keep the example to the minimal size necessary.

Comment: Actual data Branch Safety category Aug-01 Sep-02 Oct-04 Nov-04 Jan-05 Feb-05 Mar-05
MMC LTI 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
MMC NIL 1 3 6 9 2 8 1
MMC SIL 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
MMC MIL 6 5 6 7 6 9 6
SMN LTI 8 8 8 2 8 8 8
SMN NIL 4 2 4 5 2 7 4
SMN SIL 2 6 2 3 2 2 0
SMN MIL 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
EWC LTI 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
EWC NIL 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
EWC SIL 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
EWC MIL 6 25 54 3 6 3 1

Comment: Desired outputBranch Date LTI NIL SIL MIL
MMC Aug-01 0 1 4 6
MMC Sep-02 0 3 4 5
MMC Oct-04 0 6 4 6
MMC Nov-04    
MMC Jan-05    
MMC Feb-05    
MMC Mar-05    
SMN Aug-01    
SMN Sep-02    
SMN Oct-04    
SMN Nov-04    
SMN Jan-05    
SMN Feb-05    
SMN Mar-05

Comment: As I wrote above - please include data **as text in your post**. It's impossible to read in a comment. Also - please include the expected output.

Comment: Perhaps to clarify - when I write "in your post", I mean **in the body of the question**. You can edit it if you wish. I can assure you that if your question contains all the relevant data, you'll get an answer in no time :)